# JavaFX: set fullscreen exclusive mode (FSEM) in non-mouse/keyboard-handler

Tags: javafx, fullscreen

my application consists of a `TabPane` named `tabPane` with, lets say, two `Tab`s: `firstTab` and `secondTab`. Whenever `firstTab` is selected, I want the application to be in `FSEM` (`full-screen exclusive mode`, see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setFullScreen-boolean-)); otherwise it should be in normal windowed mode.

My usual way of being notified about which `Tab` is active is either

```
BooleanBinding isFirstTabActive = tabPane.getSelectionModel().
    selectedItemProperty().isEqualTo(firstTab);
```

or

```
tabPane.getSelectionModel.selectedItemProperty().addListener(...);
```

Since `stage.fullScreenProperty()` is read-only and therefore cannot be binded (as stated in docs), I can not use my first method and do, lets say,

```
stage.fullScreenProperty().bind(isFirstTabActive) //not working.
```

Since I am not planning on sigining the application for now and, as the docs state:

> Applications can only enter FSEM in response to user input. More specifically, entering is allowed from mouse (Node.mousePressed/mouseReleased/mouseClicked) or keyboard (Node.keyPressed/keyReleased/keyTyped) event handlers.

I can not use the second method either, by doing

```
tabPane.getSelectionModel.selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>() {
  @Override
  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> observable, Tab oldValue, Tab newValue) {
    stage.setFullScreen(newValue == firstTab);
  }
);
```

because this way the application does not enter `FSEM` but only emulated fullscreen mode.

I do know that I can enter `FSEM` by creating `EventHandler`s which listen to `tabPane` events. But this way I had to add two `EventHandler`s for both `MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED` and `KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED`, and the `EventHandler`s would have to explicitly find out whats going on ignoring their `Event`, like:

```
tabPane.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    stage.setFullScreen(tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == firstTab);
  }
});
```

So is this really the way to go here? Or can I do some workaround with the `Binding`s? Any suggestions here? Thanks.